# How to post json data in perl

Tags: json, perl

I'm new to Perl script and then got the problem on how to post json data for web service. I tried a template perl script I have found in the net (for testing). However, I had a problem since I cannot see the expected data that I will post. I don't know if something is wrong with this script:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = "https://domain/WebService/webservice.php";
# set custom HTTP request header fields
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $server_endpoint);
$req->header('content-type' => 'application/json');

$req->header('x-auth-token' => 'kfksj48sdfj4jd9d');

# add POST data to HTTP request body
my $post_data = '{ "value1" : "SMRT23489MER", "value2" : "7352009 ", "date" : "20140813", "time" : "2033", "info" : ["2424","324","545","565"] } ';

$req->content($post_data);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
if ($resp->is_success) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "Received reply: $message\n";
}
else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ", $resp->code, "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I tend to use Charles Proxy when I want to inspect the contents of HTTP requests I'm making with Perl (or pretty much anything else outside the browser).

Comment: What is response from server you get? Can you post it here?

Comment: *Always* `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: You can always use [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to show the contents of a data structure: `print Dumper($req);` -- having said that, it will show you the Perl data structure representing the request, rather than the HTTP request itself. You can also dump the response, `$resp`, which will have the request encoded in it.

Comment: I recommend using [the JSON module](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) - it has JSON encoding and decoding built in.

Comment: @ialarmedalien, [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) sometimes uses [JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS) as its backend, which is increasingly being seen as problematic (JSON::XS has threading issues, and has no public bug tracker). Instead I'd recommend looking at [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::PP) (which has been bundled with Perl for the last few years, so you probably already have it) and if that proves to be too slow, [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS) (which is a fork of the original JSON::XS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We would need to see the actual response you are getting in order to determine if something is wrong. However, [HTTP::Request](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Request) has a method `as_string` that will give you the textual representation of your request.

```
# ... stuff  
$req->content($post_data);

# show the request
print $req->as_string;

# ...
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
```

It will show something like this:

```
POST foo
Content-Type: application/json
X-Auth-Token: kfksj48sdfj4jd9d

{ "value1" : "SMRT23489MER", "value2" : "7352009 ", "date" : "20140813",
"time" : "2033", "info" : ["2424","324","545","565"] }
```

Which is basically a fine request as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here. On the Endpoint i get no data.
Its PHP on the other side and $_POST is still empty.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use JSON::XS;

my $url = 'http://myurl';

my $json = {'username' => 'foo' ,'password' => 'bar'};
my $req = HTTP::Request->new( 'POST', $url );
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( encode_json $json );
my $lwp = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $res = $lwp->request( $req );
```

The $req->as_string is:

```
POST http://myurl
Content-Type: application/json

{"password":"bar","username":"foo"}
```

edit:
This way do what i want. On endpoint we get the POST['json'] and can decode it to an object:

```
sub __POST {
    my ($self, $url,$obj) = @_;
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->cookie_jar( $self->{cookie} );
    my $res = $ua->post($url, { 'json' =>  encode_json $obj } );
    my $content  = $res->decoded_content();
    my $retval = eval { JSON::XS->new->utf8->decode($content); };
    if($@ || $retval->{code} != 200){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Returnvalue is also a JSON-String